# Get Host name using IP address -Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, python-3.x

I am trying to display all the connected machine names using ip address, I could get the IP address by checking the connection

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((addr,80))
```

I have tried using  `s.getsockname`,`socket.gethostname` and `s.getpeername`
these all are returning similiar results

What should I do if I need to display the names? For example

```
192.168.1.1     - 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.50    - 192.168.1.50
192.168.1.113   - 192.168.1.113
192.168.1.114   - 192.168.1.114
192.168.1.139   - 192.168.1.139
```

I need to display this like

```
192.168.1.1     - tom123
192.168.1.50    - allec
192.168.1.113   - john-pc
192.168.1.114   - bob
192.168.1.139   - anny
```

I have tried with socket.gethostbyaddr("196.168.1.114") -- it is giving me an exception saying

> ```
> print socket.gethostbyaddr("196.168.1.114")
> ```
>
> socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host

Comment: By the way, are you running this in client-side or server-side? That may make a difference

Comment: @PeterWood I think it isn't. In that case they are getting the hostname of a server. In this case he is working on a LAN.

Comment: Python lookup hostname from IP with 1 second timeout  -- I have tried it already   it is blowing up with an error message   "Unknown host name"

Comment: you could try nmap http://pastebin.com/2XUmEaj3

Comment: socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
 This is the error which i am getting after using socket.gethostbyaddr("196.168.1.114")

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help, but `socket.getfqdn(IP_ADDRESS)` returns the hostname.

Comment: I have tried with this getfqdn will only print the same host ip which you are passing , it will not work , Thanks for the response

Comment: @user3247425 why don't you post your full code? There might be something there. Or is it all there?

Comment: - But here i am already getting the ipaddress which are connected -- My remaining code is all for getting those connected ips (No issues with that) - from ip address getting name is something which i need to right new

Comment: If you cannot resolve it using `getfqdn`, your system simply cannot resolve it using /etc/hosts or DNS.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I don't get your point. I just suggested a way that I knew and I might have worked for him. Unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: My point was explaining the OP what's the reason if your code doesn't work for him...

Comment: @ThiefMaster ah all right. Thanks then for your help